# What is the Present?

Tags: riddle, steganography

My (fictional) riddle-loving friend comes up to me and says, "Hey, bro, I gave you a present. "

"Um, is this a puzzle?", you ask.

"Yes.... it's going to be a riddle", he says. You groan. It's going to be another of his crazy riddles.

He gives you a piece of paper which says:

> **I can mote**. 
> **But only rf I have a daiver**. 
> **Or peiple can ride ne**.

> People can build things out of the middle of me. 
> They can look very realistic. 
> Or they can be something out of science fiction!

> The last part is a group of things.

> What am I?

Comment: It's part of the riddle. The mistakes spell something.

Comment: +1! Pretty tricky idk if mote is a letter I meant rant or it is also a meaning a another word.

Comment: @Jingbo you have two letters wrong

Comment: I would like to _strongly discourage_ this style of attack on a puzzle. Either solve it or don't solve it; please don't seek out help from the puzzle's creator one teeny-tiny bit at a time.

Comment: Ok sorry I won’t anymore.

Comment: (Also, it's pretty rude to do this and then _delete all your comments_ so that no one else gets to benefit from your pestering of the puzzle's creator.)

Comment: Oh, I thought I could then explain it in answer, I could write again here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is

> A train LEGO set

as follows:

> Mote=move so we take so wrong letter and we get “t”;
>  Rf=if we get r;
>  daiver =driver we get a;
>  peiple=people we get I;
>  ne=me we get n

So

> train

> “LEGO” could be made into different shapes.

> “Set” is a group of things.

Maybe the final answer is

> “A Train LEGO  set”

Comment: That's clearly the correct interpretation of the first block. But I think the rest indicates that we need two other elements to follow that word. One thing that people can build things out of. One word that means a group of things. Also, please put spoiler markup on your answers. (I'll edit it in in this case.)

Comment: Also just so you know, this whole riddle is divided into three separate riddles whose answers form a phrase.

Comment: You are right! Even though it took you some time to get the correct answer, you are worthy of a +25.