# The Atom Riddles #3 Remake

Tags: riddle, wordplay, science

Scientist:

So.... [The Atom Riddles #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105614/the-atom-riddles-3) didn't go too well. It was closed for being too simple.

But I'm not going to give up! I've come back with a harder, more interesting riddle! Mwahahaha!

Part 1 (Wordplay):

> I have a nosth and a south, but I am not the earih. 
> I can attract things, but only uf they are of a certaim type.

Part 2:

> Remove a T from the answer to the last one!
> Add the mistakes! 
> Get the answer!

**Edit: Is this riddle good enough or is it just simple trivia? If not, why did this receive a downvote?**

Comment: Don't bother fixing the mistakes.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite. Part 1 is simple trivia ("north", "south", "attracting a certain type" - all straightforward, simple hints towards magnets). The "wordplay" element reuses a mechanic from a [recent riddle of yours](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/105589) and is, again, very straightforward. All the instructions are clear and there really isn't a "puzzle" element to this. These "riddles" of your seem to be very low-effort, just describing something the simplest way possible. Therefore, I downvoted.

Comment: Agreed, this is a task list more than it's a puzzle, but it isn't half bad, just very, very easy, and there are places and uses for easy puzzles. Therefore, I upvoted.

Comment: You can check your user page's reputation tab if you are confused about the number of upvotes and downvotes your question got. Also, people are free to vote as they please, and explaining why their reasons for voting is purely optional (although encouraged.)

Comment: I like your enthusiasm, I think one thing to consider for next time is avoiding any instructions.  Everything the puzzler needs to do to solve the riddle should be part of the puzzle rather than explicitly explained (specifically referring to the second half).  For instance, you could have written a cryptic clue such that a user who thinks they have the answer will know they are correct if it matches the last clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a nosth and a south, but I am not the earih.
I can attract things, but only uf they are of a certaim type.

> This part clues MAGNET, which has a North and South Pole, and can attract magnetic things.

Remove a T from the answer to the last one!
Add the mistakes!
Get the answer!

> Mistakes are S (nosth), I (earih), U (uf), M (certaim). MAGNET - T + SIUM = MAGNESIUM.